# LaTex, XeTex, PdfTex and git: remove anything that is regenerated during build when git version control used

Tags: xetex, git

Over my text I apply version control via git and I use the `.gitignore` file to place any file that is autogenerated on "compile" from tex to pdf.

Sometimes is nessasary to wipe out all theese file and keep the one you actually really need, because all these files are recorded in `.gitignore` one I want some magical way to do that. How is possible?

I usually keep the `.bib` files for bibliography and `.tex` for the actual content, also I keep and `.png` and `.gif` files for my text's image. My `.gitignore` is:

```
*.blg
*.out
*.pdf
*.log
*.bbl
*.aux
*.run.xml
*.synctex.gz
*.toc
*-blx.bib
*.swp
qt_temp.*
assets/.~lock.*#
dummy_for_stackeschange.*
sample*
```

I "compile" using TexStudio that runs the following compilation command:

```
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

The tree structure is of the tracked files looks like:

```
|-- .
|--- content
|----- img1.png
|----- ...
|----- some other image.png
|--- material.bib
|--- assay.tex
|--- .gitignore
```

Comment: As it stands, this is a pure Git question so off-topic for us.

Comment: Well I believe yes and no because it may be focused on git but itended for tex authors where may have a little knowledge on git. Also I enchanced it in order to make it more tex-like.

Comment: How exactly do you compile? The `latexmk` tool has a clean feature, that can be extended to include extensions it does not already know to delete

Comment: updated the question in order to add extra info. Also you can add extra answer and spread the knowledge ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I used the following command

```
git clean -xf
```

Where the command actually says "Remove anything **untracked** and anything that is in `.gitignore` files". So before running this command add/commit the files you need eg. images via:

```
git add ^file^
git commit -m "^Some change message^" ^files changed^
```

Also for images and anything binary use [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) as well, theese files are usefull for further collaboration as well.